# Is it ok to start learning Japanese?

Tags: culture

I'm not english, and I find my English to be 'good'. I can pretty much live in an English country with a slight boost of vocabulary and a bit of knowledge about the culture. But of course, I'm not even close to a native person and I still need more work on my English to be able to call it truly "good".

My question is: Should I start learning Japanese as a third language with my imperfect second language? I'm just worried about this.

Comment: This type of question is off-topic.

Comment: Why would we say it is not ok to start learning Japanese...?

Comment: Advice of this sort isn't really on-topic here, as we like to focus on questions about the Japanese language itself.  It might be on-topic on the proposed [language learning](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82841/language-learning) site, but that site hasn't launched yet.

Comment: So sorry for posting an off-topic question, I'm new to the whole thing and didn't pay much attention. I'll be careful from now on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learning two languages at the same time is a bad idea *if you're a beginner at both*.

However, by your post, it seems you already have a good grasp of English. By now you should be able to branch off into a third language without confusing your brain, or "forgetting English".